# Rails ActionMailer - Prevent email deliveries for testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I'm trying to prevent emails from being delivered so I can inspect the contents of `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries` for testing in a staging environment. I have `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test` in my environment settings but Rails is still attempting to deliver the emails and the deliveries array is empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In which environment settings specifically?

Comment: I'm testing it out in my dev environment but I'm ultimately going to use it in a staging environment. I want to log the emails to the database instead of delivering them.

Comment: In which file did you set the `delivery_method` config? Does your runtime config match w/ the environment you set it in? What version of RoR? etc.

Comment: `config/environments/development.rb`. I even double checked in the rails console that `Rails.application.config.action_mailer.delivery_method` is set properly. Rails 6.1.1

Comment: is `config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries` set to `false`?

Comment: No. Won't that prevent deliveries completely?

Comment: Sorry, I misread. It's set to nil.

Comment: Does fixing that resolve the issue?

Comment: No. Setting it to true does the same thing. Setting it to false prevent the mail from sending at all.

Comment: Scratch that. Setting it to true does deliver and get caught in the deliveries array. But reloading the app clears that array, so that's a different issue. Interesting.

Comment: @kid_drew it clears the array because the deliveries array is designed to be used for testing only

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other commenter that the best way to prevent all deliveries is through the action_mailer config.

However, if you want an alternative approach that would allow you to redirect any mail, or halt delivery based on a dynamic set of conditions, etc., then I would encourage you to check out Mail Interceptors:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#intercepting-emails